# Why VueJS is autoreloading after a push array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When i push a value in my array with VueJS, chrome display it but just after my web page is reloading.

```
let vm = new Vue ({
    el:'#app2',

    data: {
        people: ['Robert', 'Pablo', 'Lucas', 'Teban']
    },

    methods: {
        addPerson: function() {
            this.people.push('Maxime')   
        },
    }
})

    <section id="app2" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <p>{{people}}</p>
        <form>
            <button v-on:click='addPerson'>Ajouter une personne</button>
        </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: can you share more code. There doesnt seem to be much problem here

Comment: Are you sure the element triggering `addPerson()` is not reloading the page? E.g. it is a `<button>` or an `<a>` element and you didn't use `event.preventDefault()` (or set `type="button"` for the former?

Comment: <section id="app2" style="margin-top: 100px">
            <p>{{people}}</p>
            <form>
                <button v-on:click='addPerson'>Ajouter une personne</button>
            </form>
        </section>

Comment: As @Terry said, if you are using a button click event, you have to set the type="button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `<button>` element is submitting the form. When it's `type` is not defined, [it is set to `submit` by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), which causes the form to submit (and therefore reloading/refreshing your page):

> `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

To prevent that, you can use:

```
<button v-on:click='addPerson' type='button'>Ajouter une personne</button>
```

Or use the [`prevent` event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) on the click directive:

```
<button v-on:click.prevent='addPerson'>Ajouter une personne</button>
```

Or invoke `event.preventDefault()` directly in the method:

```
methods: {
    addPerson: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.people.push('Maxime')   
    },
}
```